# Making an animation of a line following a half circle using python Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, animation, uibutton

As the title says, I am attempting to make a metronome animation however, I am unsure of what to do from this point. Right now, I have been successful in animating a stick that moves up and down from a fixed point however, the issue that I have run into is making that stick move back in forth in a half circle (like a metronome does). Here is my code so far

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import matplotlib

i = 80

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
fig.add_subplot(111).plot(1,4)

points = (1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xfixdata, yfixdata = 10, 5
xdata, ydata = 5, 10
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro-', animated=True)
plt.plot([xfixdata], [yfixdata], 'bo', ms=10)

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 20)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 20)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
    # ydata = points[frame]
    ydata = np.sin(1 + (1 + 2*frame))
    ln.set_data([xfixdata,xdata], [yfixdata,ydata])
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=i, init_func=init, blit=True)
plt.axis('on')


def draw_figure(canvas, figure):
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
    return figure_canvas_agg


#Gui Code

# define the window layout
layout = [[sg.Text('UI Test')],
          [sg.Canvas(key='-CANVAS-')],
          [sg.Button('Speed Up'), sg.Button('Slow Down')],
          [sg.Text(i)],
          [sg.Button('Exit')]
          ]


# create the form and show it without the plot
window = sg.Window('UI Test For Conductor Robot', layout, finalize=True,
                   element_justification='center', font='Helvetica 18')


# add the plot to the window
fig_canvas_agg = draw_figure(window['-CANVAS-'].TKCanvas, fig)

event, values = window.read()

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == "Speed Up":
        i = i + 10


window.close()
```

Also, another problem that I am having is making a button that increases the speed of the animation. As you can see in the code I created an I value that stores the value 80. I then set the interval to I and made a button that when pressed is supposed to increase the value of I by 10, therefore, slowing down the speed of the animation however, it does not work. If you could help with this it would be nice however, the main problem that I  am concerned about at the moment is making the animation of the metronome. Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Library `Matplotlib` is not necessary for `PySimpleGUI` used here.

Example Code here just to demo the animation, bpm is not correct or exact, also no sound here.

```py
import math
import time
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def func(window):
    global running
    while running:
        time.sleep(0.031)
        window.write_event_value('Update', None)
    window.write_event_value('Done', None)

h, pad, range1, range2 = 160, 20, 40, 200
size = ((h+pad)*2, h+pad)
bpm, step = 60, -4
max_angle = 3000/bpm
angle = 90 + max_angle

sg.theme('Dark')
layout = [
    [sg.Graph(size, (-h-pad, 0), (h+pad, h+pad), background_color='green', key='-GRAPH-')],
    [sg.Slider((range1, range2), default_value=bpm, resolution=4, tick_interval=16, orientation='h', enable_events=True, expand_x=True, key='-Slider-')]
]
window = sg.Window('Metronome', layout, margins=(0, 0), finalize=True, enable_close_attempted_event=True)

graph = window['-GRAPH-']
pointer = graph.draw_line((0, -pad), (h*math.cos(angle/180*math.pi), h*math.sin(angle/180*math.pi)), color='white', width=5)
running = True
thread = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(window,), daemon=True)
thread.start()

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT:
        running = False
    elif event == 'Update':
        graph.delete_figure(pointer)
        angle += step
        if step < 0 and angle <= 90 - max_angle:
            angle = 90 - max_angle
            step = -step
        elif step > 0 and angle >= 90 + max_angle:
            angle = 90 + max_angle
            step = -step
        pointer = graph.draw_line((0, -pad), (h*math.cos(angle/180*math.pi), h*math.sin(angle/180*math.pi)), color='white', width=5)
    elif event == '-Slider-':
        bpm = values[event]
        max_angle = 3000//bpm
    elif event == 'Done':
        break

window.close()
```

[image]